# Creating GET request with json parameters

Tags: ios, json, get, httprequest

I'm trying to create GET request with json parameters but I get an error and I don't know why.
I have this example link, with parameters in the end
http://testlink.ru/link=get_user&data={"login":"test"}
Please help, Thanks!

Comment: what is the error u r getting? what code have u used? please add.

Comment: Have u tried the GET request on a browser or some other tool?

Comment: @Nishant Yes, when I tried this request in browser all is ok
{"login":"test"}  it is parameters which I  should post where object is test and key is login

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of your parameters is a full-on object. If you know what parameters you want to send, you can break it out into components (ie: login=test&somethingelse=othervalue). Most frameworks help you out with that. What framework are you using?

Comment: Ah. I'm really rusty on AFNetworking. I'm sure there's a built-in way to do it (this looks promising: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.6.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html ), but worst case scenario you could just add each key-value pair to the URL string manually.